# Want to incorporate progress bar when uploading file using Google.Apis.Drive.v3 with C# MVC 5

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, google-drive-api

I am using google drive api v3 in my c# mvc project to CRUD large file onto my google drive. I am performing resumable upload for this purpose. I need to incorporate a progress bar for this matter. Progress bar/spinner whatever i tried to use, It only shows for local uploading time part. Then spinner/bar vanishes but the upload is still in progress to the drive. Here is my c# function for uploading file(large file)

```
public static void FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            string pathDelete = string.Empty;
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                DriveService service = GetService();

                string path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/GoogleDriveFiles"),
                Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                file.SaveAs(path);
                try
                {
                    System.IO.FileInfo info = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);

                    ulong fileSize = (ulong)info.Length;

                    var uploadStream = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

                    var insert = service.Files.Create(new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File { Name = file.FileName, Parents = new List<string> { "root" } }, uploadStream, "application/octet-stream");

                    Uri uploadUri = insert.InitiateSessionAsync().Result;

                    int chunk_size = ResumableUpload.MinimumChunkSize;
                    int bytesSent = 0;
                    while (uploadStream.Length != uploadStream.Position)
                    {
                        byte[] temp = new byte[chunk_size];
                        int cnt = uploadStream.Read(temp, 0, temp.Length);
                        if (cnt == 0)
                            break;

                        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uploadUri);

                        httpRequest.Method = "PUT";
                        httpRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + ((UserCredential)service.HttpClientInitializer).Token.AccessToken;
                        httpRequest.ContentLength = (long)cnt;
                        httpRequest.Headers["Content-Range"] = string.Format("bytes {0}-{1}/{2}", bytesSent, bytesSent + cnt - 1, fileSize);

                        using (System.IO.Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync().Result)
                        {
                            requestStream.Write(temp, 0, cnt);
                        }

                        HttpWebResponse httpResponse;
                        try
                        {
                            httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
                        }
                        catch (WebException ex)
                        {
                            httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                        }

                        if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        { }
                        else if ((int)httpResponse.StatusCode != 308)
                            break;

                        bytesSent += cnt;

                        Debug.WriteLine("Uploaded " + bytesSent.ToString());
                    }

                    if (bytesSent != uploadStream.Length)
                    {
                        //return null;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

and in my view

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p>
                <label for="file">Upload file:</label>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="fileSubmit" />
                <div class="spinner-border" style="display:none" role="status">
                    <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                </div>
            </p>
        </form>
<script>
$("#fileSubmit").click(function () {
        var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open("POST", "/Home/UploadFile");

        ajax.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
            $(".spinner-border").css("display", "block");
            //if (e.lengthComputable) {
            //    //updating progress bar here
            //    $("#progressBardiv").attr('max', e.total);
            //    $("#progressBardiv").css('width', e.loaded);

            //}
        }

        ajax.upload.onloadstart = function (e) {
            //updating progress bar on strt of AJAX request
            $(".spinner-border").css("display", "none");

        }
        ajax.upload.onloadend = function (e) {
            //called on file upload is done.
            $(".spinner-border").css("display", "none");

        }

        ajax.send(formData);
    });
<script/>
```

Another thing, Is there any way that i could upload file to google drive without saving it to the project directory first?

Comment: What is the issue with your current solution?

Comment: the loader/progress bar gets completed after the local folder upload(browser default upload) time. Actually just after that..the google drive upload begins. I need that time also. I need to show the loader during the whole process is undergoing. Local and g Drive uploading time.